Let $ A_{m\times n}$ and $ B_{n\times m}$ be matrices such that m >n.
Let $\displaystyle A_{m\times n}$ and $\displaystyle B_{n\times m}$ be matrices such that $\displaystyle m >n$.
Prove that if the matrix BA is invertible then $\displaystyle \rho ( AB) =\rho ( B) =\rho ( A) =n\ $
I have proved $\displaystyle \rho ( A) =$ $\displaystyle \rho ( B) =n$. which was pretty easy, however I couldn't finish the rest.
I know that the columns of A are linearly independent and the rows of B are linearly independent.
In addition, $\displaystyle \rho ( AB) <= n$ and $\rho (BA) = n$
So how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

$\rho$ is the rank?

If so, just prove that $ker(AB) = ker(B)$

@Exodd Yes it is but I can't use Ker as we didn't learn it yet, I think it should be something with dim/linear independence or nullity

@Shai What do you mean... "I can't use Ker as we didn't learn it yet...should be something with... nullity"?  How else can you possibly define nullity if not through talking about the kernel?  Nullity is the dimension of the kernel... by definition.  Perhaps you are just confused because you use a different word for the kernel... such as the nullspace.

@JMoravitz Yes possibly I got confused, so how can I prove that ker(AB)=ker(B)?

Clearly $ker(B)\subseteq ker(AB)$ since for $x\in ker(B)$ that means that $Bx=0$ and so $(AB)x = A(Bx)=A(0)=0$.  Now, you can make a nullity argument that these should be the same dimension and as such equal.
